# How can I determine the relationship between spam and weekdays?

Tags: python, correlation, numpy

I am trying to check if there is a correlation between spam emails and weekdays.
My dataset looks like as follows:

```
  Spam? Day
0   1.0 Saturday
1   1.0 Saturday
3   0.0 Saturday
5   1.0 Saturday
7   0.0 Friday
... ... ...
346 0.0 Friday
348 1.0 Friday
361 0.0 Saturday
383 1.0 Thursday
387 1.0 Friday
```

where 1 means spam and 0 not spam.

I have tried as follows

```
corr = (numpy.corrcoef(df['Spam?'],df['Days']))
```

I do not know how to explain a possible relationship between these two variables and if a plot could help to better visualise data and relationship.

Comment: Do you mean to see if there is a difference between volume of spam received on weekdays compared to the weekend?

Comment: yes, I am trying to analyse some aspect of sending spam, trying to understand what could be interesting to be investigated. So I wanted determine if there is a correlation between the volume of spam received on weekdays compared to the weekend. But other type of suggestions would be greatly appreciated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(started as a comment but it turned out to be longer than expected)

With a dataset like this a simple barplot could be very insightful: on the X axis the days of the week, on the Y axis the frequency, with two bars (spam/not spam using different color) for each day. A slightly more advanced version: two boxplots, one for weekdays the other for weekends. A boxplot is kind of overkill for only 5 (mon-fri) and 2 (sat-sun) values but it's easy to do and shows the big picture.

In order to test whether any difference (e.g. weekdays vs weekends) is significant I think this is a good case for a chi square test.

Answer (score 3):

*numpy.corrcoef* will gives you Pearson Correlation but your Features are Categorical.

You should calculate Crammer'v.

You can get details/code in this answer as both the questions are a bit similar [DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/80942/58341)

**On Plot**

 What Erwan has suggested seems good.

Also, try to plot(*line-plot*) between days-of-week and spam/total ratio(*i.e. Stanardizing for total volume*) since a single figure is easier to comprehend.

Comment: thanks for your answer 10xAl